# How to trigger an Apex Trigger or a Flow on change of formula field value?

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, formula-field

How can I update the 'Type__c' field on a Contact object based on a cross object formula field in a related child object? I only want to update the 'Type__c' field if the value in the cross object formula field on the child record has changed.

I have researched but I didn't found any relevant solution.

**Updated the question**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question as written is:
**you can't**.

Formula fields are calculated every time the SObject record is queried, the data stored in these formula fields is literally the formula itself. The stored formula isn't changing, and you can't write a value to a formula field, so there is nothing that can cause a trigger (or other automation, like a record-triggered flow) to fire.

If the formula on your child object only uses data from that child object (i.e. it's not a cross-object formula like `Recordtype.Name == 'MyRectype'`), then any change to the calculated value of the formula *must* be due to a change on another field within your child object. That would get you into a trigger (or other automation), and from there you could run a DML update on the parent records. If you have a rollup summary field on the parent object (summarizing the formula field on the child object), then explicitly doing DML on the parent records may not be required (though I'm not 100% sure if the automatic parent update behavior works when you summarize a formula field).

If this is a cross-object formula, then you may need to go one step further. If the change in the calculated value is due to a change on the other, referenced SObject, then you'd fire a trigger on that other SObject.

Other SObject's trigger -> DML update the child SObject -> child SObject trigger fires -> DML update the parent SObject -> parent SObject trigger fires

Comment: Actually that formula field is cross object formula field that.